# Custom commerce payment methods based on item

Tags: 7, commerce

In my Drupal commerce website, I have 2 payment methods, Payment Method #1, Payment Method #2

This is working just fine but the thing is I need to make it custom for a specific product type, for example if I'm selling Asus products, I want to get 40% pay with Payment Method #1 and the rest via Payment Method #2.

I'm not a module developer so I thought I can make it happen with some customization and/or rules.

I'd like to know if it's possible without module development,what's the best approach and how to do it properly.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An administrator can add two payment transactions to an order using different payment methods from the admin > order > payment area.

However an end-user normally selects a single payment method from the radio button form during checkout.

To support multiple payment methods you may need to send the customer through the payment step of the checkout twice, each time with a different amount and a different payment method selected.

Payment method selection is controlled by Rules logic and can be configured there.
The order status controls whether it can be sent through checkout again so may need to be set to the relevant checkout status. 
The order amount to be paid may need to be set in custom code during the payment step process.

Comment: So what I get from your answer is that I send the user through Payment method #1, then redirect it back to paymenth method #2, am I correct? using rules and setting two payment transactions.

and for setting the percentage to be used for each of these payment methods must be done with custom code?

Comment: Yes, without knowing more about the payment methods and business logic, the two payment pages approach with Rules and some custom code is a reasonable solution and should work.